# How to implement JMS message auto clone?

Tags: jms

Is there any way can let WLS auto clone JMS message from a queue and send it to another queue?

Currently, I want to implement auto backup feature for JMS messsage. That means once Queue-A receives a new jms message, it can dupilicate this message and sends it to another JMS Queue,Queue-B, to backup original message from Queue-A.

I think that this feature could be fulfilled by WLS configration. But I need some guides to show me how to do it.

Comment: You may want to try out Bridge feature for doing that

Comment: Yes, sth like that, but for my understanding Bridge feature only supports clone one message from a domain to another domain. It doesn't support clone message in same domain.